# CSS transform like netflix cover image

Tags: css, image, transform, netflix

I tried to transform an image that it looks like this image from [netflix](https://www.netflix.com/de/login): [background-image](https://assets.nflxext.com/ffe/siteui/vlv3/ba64c2ca-d0e9-4216-8d92-d0dc621ad5be/50256392-5e93-4448-bc65-a2d343cb0e36/DE-de-20190715-popsignuptwoweeks-perspective_alpha_website_large.jpg)

```
transform: rotateY(-30deg) rotateX(30deg);
perspective: 800px;
transform-origin: 50% 0;
```

But there is something missing ...

Comment: @slhck No sorry. I don't know the combination of rotation and other ways to transform the image

Comment: What do you mean, you don't know the combination? Have you tried the methods shown in the other question?

Comment: Yes i tried them. There is no need of a shorter code version. I don't know how to transform an image that it looks like the netflix one.

Comment: perspective on the parent element OR inside the transform

Comment: @temani-afif, oh dear! That's great :)

Comment: Your initial question only used X and Y coordinates, so I wasn't sure you knew about 3D rotations…

Comment: @slhck we explicitely rotate around X and Y to create 3D rotations. The rotation on Z will do no 3D effect

Answer (score -1):

I think this is approximately what you're looking for, rotate3d() css function :

`transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 1, 35deg);`