# How do I recreate the Disney Plus / Netflix cover image with CSS?

Tags: css, css-transforms

I have a background image on my website. I want to skew it so that it looks like cover photos on Netflix / Disney Plus (attached below).

### Attempt

I tried adding this to my image's CSS, inspired from this question: [CSS transform like netflix cover image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57146289/css-transform-like-netflix-cover-image)

```css
transform: rotateY(-30deg) rotateX(40deg) perspective(800px) scale(1.6)
```

It doesn't produce the desired result, though. Instead it slants incorrectly and doesn't stretch the container entirely.

### Code sample

Here is my example: https://jsfiddle.net/gd3wL8nk/11/

### Screenshots

[image: Netflix Image]

[image: Disney Pllus]

## Update

I got it to work by adding `perspective: 2000px` to the containing div, and adding this to the inner div:

```css
transform: rotateY(-20deg) rotateX(20deg) scale(2) translateX(-10%)
```

My final CSS (with edits for measurement, etc) looked like this:

```css
.container {
  height: 90vh;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  perspective: 2000px;
  height: 900
}

.bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 110%;
  background-image: url('image-here');
  background-size: cover;
  transform: rotateY(-20deg) rotateX(20deg) scale(2);
  position: absolute;
  top: -10%;
  left: 0;
  minWidth: 800;
}
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fernandorojo/kr567zp8/4/

Comment: Where can we see your output?

Comment: @m4n0 I just added this link to my example: https://jsfiddle.net/gd3wL8nk/11/

Comment: Can you try applying perspective on the parent element?

Comment: That certainly made difference: https://jsfiddle.net/0e9ohpu3/1/. Maybe I'll keep tweaking the perspective now. The final thing to figure out is how to 1) get the exact(ish) angle they used, and 2) make sure it always fills the container.

Comment: I think I got it, I shared my solution in my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for `transform: skew();`!

i.e.

```
transform: skew(20deg) scale(1.6);
```

It won't work with both X and Y rotation though. A good method to ensure it's fullscreen is to use the image as a background in an oversized container. For any children items (like the form, if you nest it in the parent div) you will need to apply the opposite skew to ensure it appears without a slant.

If you check [the asset Netflix uses](https://assets.nflxext.com/ffe/siteui/vlv3/8dc3f88b-a96a-4d8a-af9a-a69e6f3b2506/f5dda23e-4470-4f6a-8037-f8905acbb350/US-en-20210524-popsignuptwoweeks-perspective_alpha_website_small.jpg), it's been skewed in Photoshop already.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed theirs was a skewed raster already. Maybe I'll try to do that (although that's yet another thing to figure out). The reason I wanted to do it in CSS is that I'm hoping to have actual elements there that are animating, rather than just a single static image. Here's another example that does this with CSS (although it appears to be just on one axis): https://storyheap.com/